# Spark : How to provide "--properties-file" option in Eclipse IDE development

Tags: eclipse, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I used Eclipse to develop my spark application , while running from command line, i use command something like this:

```
spark-submit  --master yarn-client --driver-memory 4g --properties-file  myAPP.conf ..
```

I can also run my main class from eclipse IDE directly, but can anyone suggestion , how to give --properties-file option while running from IDE directly.

Thanks
Alok

Answer (score 1):

Add the configuration file to your project and add these lines

```
  val configuration = new Configuration()
  val conffile = getClass().getResourceAsStream("filepath");
  configuration.addResource(conffile)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the properties into a properties file and pass that file name as a command line argument.

Consume the file name within the Scala/Java program and add the properties to `SparkConf`. A sample scala snippet is shown below

```
import java.io.FileInputStream
import java.util.Properties
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import scala.collection.JavaConverters

....

val properties: Properties = new Properties()
properties.load(new FileInputStream("spark.properties"))

val map = JavaConverters.propertiesAsScalaMapConverter(properties).asScala;

val sparkConf = new SparkConf().setAppName("SampleJob").setAll(map)
```

All the property names and values should be in the properties format i.e., `--driver-memory` translates to `spark.driver.memory`.